Scrapy: parsing website about new buildings returns None
I need to parse this page "https://xn--80az8a.xn--d1aqf.xn--p1ai/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA?place=0-1&objStatus=0" I wrote the code, but it returns None, I don’t know why, as if it just doesn’t find the CSS selector, please help, I’ve been stuck with this problem for 3 days.
import scrapy


class BuildingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "building"
    allowed_domains = ["xn--80az8a.xn--d1aqf.xn--p1ai"]
    start_urls = ["https://xn--80az8a.xn--d1aqf.xn--p1ai/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA?place=0-44&objStatus=0"]

    def parse(self, response):
        buildings = response.css('div.Newbuildings__NewBuildingList-sc-1bou0u4-14.huMfny')
        
        if not buildings:
            print("Ничего не найдено")
        else:
            for building in buildings:
                print("Объект недвижимости найден")
                
                link = building.css('a.NewBuildingItem__ImageWrapper-sc-o36w9y-2 iLOAue::attr(href)').get()
                title = building.css('a.NewBuildingItem__MainTitle-sc-o36w9y-6 KYYzh::text').get()
                address = building.css('p.NewBuildingItem__Text-sc-o36w9w-7.iUiqkY::text').get()
                building_id = building.css('p.NewBuildingItem__Text-sc-o36w9y-7.NewBuildingItem__ObjectID-sc-o36w9y-8.iUiqkY.cgrVoh::text').get()
                commissioning = building.css('p.NewBuildingItem__InfoValue-sc-o36w9y-11.jZCQkA::text').get()
                developer = building.css('p.NewBuildingItem__InfoValue-sc-o36w9y-11.jZCQkA::text').get()

                yield {
                    'link': link,
                    'title': title,
                    'address': address,
                    'id': building_id,
                    'commissioning': commissioning,
                    'developer': developer
                }

HTML:
<div class="NewBuildingItem__Wrapper-sc-o36w9y-0 iYDe"><div class="NewBuildingItem__Inner-sc-o36w9y-1 pBaPl"><a href="https://xn--80az8a.xn--d1aqf.xn--p1ai/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82/60491" class="NewBuildingItem__ImageWrapper-sc-o36w9y-2 iLOAue"><img src="https://xn--80az8a.xn--d1aqf.xn--p1ai/api/ext/file/70726F6A6465636C2E646F63732E697A643A27D62169E934448C8AE6A6A9A6122C02" class="NewBuildingItem__Image-sc-o36w9y-3 gxPtNA"></a><div class="NewBuildingItem__DataRows-sc-o36w9y-13 gtIOyH"><div class="NewBuildingItem__Row-sc-o36w9y-14 iSPtSM"><div class="NewBuildingItem__InfoBlock-sc-o36w9y-15 iPvXby"><div class="NewBuildingItem__MainTitleWrapper-sc-o36w9y-5 beVblz"><div color="#0085FF" class="HouseStatus__CompactStatus-sc-2y8yk1-3 eyztuY"></div><a href="https://xn--80az8a.xn--d1aqf.xn--p1ai/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82/60491" class="NewBuildingItem__MainTitle-sc-o36w9y-6 KYYzh">Многофункциональный комплекс "Парк"</a></div><div class="NewBuildingItem__ObjectDataWrapper-sc-o36w9y-9 cQZVyr"><p class="NewBuildingItem__Text-sc-o36w9y-7 iUiqkY">Краснодарский край, город Г Сочи, Проспект Курортный</p><p class="NewBuildingItem__Text-sc-o36w9y-7 NewBuildingItem__ObjectID-sc-o36w9y-8 iUiqkY cgrVoh">ID:&nbsp;<!-- -->60491</p></div></div><div class="NewBuildingItem__ButtonsBlock-sc-o36w9y-17 bRGNJI"><button class="FavoriteButton__AddToFavoriteWrapper-sc-1dlzy3y-0 lRxJR"><svg fill="none" height="25" viewBox="0 0 24 25" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.547 7.27C11.516 7.97 12 8.696 12 8.696s.42-.757 1.396-1.47c.25-.182.535-.361.86-.524.801-.403 1.838-.706 3.144-.706 2.1 0 3.6 1.8 3.6 3.9 0 3.6-5.4 8.1-9 10.5-3.6-2.4-9-6.9-9-10.5 0-2.1 1.5-3.9 3.6-3.9a6.638 6.638 0 0 1 3.947 1.274Zm1.398-1.452a8.067 8.067 0 0 1 1.412-.903c1.071-.538 2.415-.919 4.043-.919 3.408 0 5.6 2.91 5.6 5.9 0 1.385-.512 2.696-1.172 3.829-.668 1.147-1.569 2.25-2.535 3.256-1.933 2.013-4.308 3.829-6.184 5.08a2 2 0 0 1-2.218 0c-1.876-1.251-4.251-3.067-6.184-5.08-.966-1.007-1.867-2.109-2.535-3.256C1.512 12.592 1 11.28 1 9.896c0-2.99 2.192-5.9 5.6-5.9 1.607 0 2.953.42 4.016.973.51.265.952.559 1.33.85Z" fill="#686A7A" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></button><button style="cursor:pointer" class="ComparisonButton__AddToComparison-sc-qggtzt-0 lzbqf"><svg class="SVGIcon__StyledSVGIcon-sc-1fzgsce-0 icCsZM" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none"><path d="m1.525 2.5556h9.15v0.79325c0 0.42104 0.3413 0.76239 0.7623 0.7625 0.4212 1e-4 0.7627-0.34131 0.7627-0.7625v-1.3488c0-0.55229-0.4477-1-1-1h-10.2c-0.55228 0-1 0.44772-1 1v12c0 0.5523 0.44772 1 1 1h10.2c0.5523 0 1-0.4477 1-1v-1.3486c0-0.4211-0.3414-0.7625-0.7625-0.7625s-0.7625 0.3414-0.7625 0.7625v0.793h-9.15v-10.889z" fill="currentColor"></path><path d="m3.0977 4.8098c0-0.42079 0.34111-0.76191 0.7619-0.76191h4.673c0.42079 0 0.7619 0.34112 0.7619 0.76191s-0.34111 0.7619-0.7619 0.7619h-4.673c-0.42079 0-0.7619-0.34111-0.7619-0.7619z" fill="currentColor"></path><path d="m3.0977 7.8576c0-0.42079 0.34111-0.76191 0.7619-0.76191h1.5746c0.42079 0 0.76191 0.34112 0.76191 0.76191s-0.34112 0.7619-0.76191 0.7619h-1.5746c-0.42079 0-0.7619-0.34111-0.7619-0.7619z" fill="currentColor"></path><path d="m3.8596 10.143c-0.42079 0-0.7619 0.3411-0.7619 0.7619s0.34111 0.7619 0.7619 0.7619h3.8984c0.42079 0 0.76191-0.3411 0.76191-0.7619s-0.34112-0.7619-0.76191-0.7619h-3.8984z" fill="currentColor"></path><path d="m13.714 5.5714c0-0.42079-0.3412-0.7619-0.7619-0.7619-0.4208 0-0.7619 0.34111-0.7619 0.7619v1.5238h-1.5239c-0.4207 0-0.76186 0.34112-0.76186 0.76191s0.34116 0.7619 0.76186 0.7619h1.5239v1.5238c0 0.4208 0.3411 0.7619 0.7619 0.7619 0.4207 0 0.7619-0.3411 0.7619-0.7619v-1.5238h1.5238c0.4208 0 0.7619-0.34111 0.7619-0.7619s-0.3411-0.76191-0.7619-0.76191h-1.5238v-1.5238z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg></button></div></div><div class="NewBuildingItem__Row-sc-o36w9y-14 iSPtSM"><div class="NewBuildingItem__InfoBlock-sc-o36w9y-15 NewBuildingItem__LableValue-sc-o36w9y-16 iPvXby bHceKv"><div><p class="NewBuildingItem__Text-sc-o36w9y-7 NewBuildingItem__InfoLabel-sc-o36w9y-10 iUiqkY esfvPl">Ввод в эксплуатацию</p><p class="NewBuildingItem__InfoValue-sc-o36w9y-11 jZCQkA">IV кв. 2026</p></div><div><p class="NewBuildingItem__Text-sc-o36w9y-7 NewBuildingItem__InfoLabel-sc-o36w9y-10 iUiqkY esfvPl">Застройщик</p><p class="NewBuildingItem__InfoValue-sc-o36w9y-11 jZCQkA">ООО СЗ ИМПЕРИАЛ</p></div></div><div class="NewBuildingItem__TransportBlock-sc-o36w9y-18 iugPIG"></div></div></div></div></div>

I tried changing the css selector in the code, no matter how much I changed the code, nothing helped.

Please post the HTML in question instead of having us go to a very hacky looking URL

If you look at your response you will most likely see an antibot page instead of the actual content.

I posted the html code, I'm waiting for a response, thanks in advance!

Is that the HTML you received?

Yes, this is html code from the page that needs to be parsed

So no. It doesn't matter, what matters is what you actually receive.

what should I do so that I can parse the site?

There are many possible ways to defeat antibot protection, depending on the specifics of it.

I could not get the page source using the URL provided.
However, using the HTML fragment I'd suggest alternative CSS selectors that are more robust against randomised class names.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HTML = """
<div class="NewBuildingItem__Wrapper-sc-o36w9y-0 iYDe"><div class="NewBuildingItem__Inner-sc-o36w9y-1 pBaPl"><a href="https://xn--80az8a.xn--d1aqf.xn--p1ai/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82/60491" class="NewBuildingItem__ImageWrapper-sc-o36w9y-2 iLOAue"><img src="https://xn--80az8a.xn--d1aqf.xn--p1ai/api/ext/file/70726F6A6465636C2E646F63732E697A643A27D62169E934448C8AE6A6A9A6122C02" class="NewBuildingItem__Image-sc-o36w9y-3 gxPtNA"></a><div class="NewBuildingItem__DataRows-sc-o36w9y-13 gtIOyH"><div class="NewBuildingItem__Row-sc-o36w9y-14 iSPtSM"><div class="NewBuildingItem__InfoBlock-sc-o36w9y-15 iPvXby"><div class="NewBuildingItem__MainTitleWrapper-sc-o36w9y-5 beVblz"><div color="#0085FF" class="HouseStatus__CompactStatus-sc-2y8yk1-3 eyztuY"></div><a href="https://xn--80az8a.xn--d1aqf.xn--p1ai/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82/60491" class="NewBuildingItem__MainTitle-sc-o36w9y-6 KYYzh">Многофункциональный комплекс "Парк"</a></div><div class="NewBuildingItem__ObjectDataWrapper-sc-o36w9y-9 cQZVyr"><p class="NewBuildingItem__Text-sc-o36w9y-7 iUiqkY">Краснодарский край, город Г Сочи, Проспект Курортный</p><p class="NewBuildingItem__Text-sc-o36w9y-7 NewBuildingItem__ObjectID-sc-o36w9y-8 iUiqkY cgrVoh">ID:&nbsp;<!-- -->60491</p></div></div><div class="NewBuildingItem__ButtonsBlock-sc-o36w9y-17 bRGNJI"><button class="FavoriteButton__AddToFavoriteWrapper-sc-1dlzy3y-0 lRxJR"><svg fill="none" height="25" viewBox="0 0 24 25" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.547 7.27C11.516 7.97 12 8.696 12 8.696s.42-.757 1.396-1.47c.25-.182.535-.361.86-.524.801-.403 1.838-.706 3.144-.706 2.1 0 3.6 1.8 3.6 3.9 0 3.6-5.4 8.1-9 10.5-3.6-2.4-9-6.9-9-10.5 0-2.1 1.5-3.9 3.6-3.9a6.638 6.638 0 0 1 3.947 1.274Zm1.398-1.452a8.067 8.067 0 0 1 1.412-.903c1.071-.538 2.415-.919 4.043-.919 3.408 0 5.6 2.91 5.6 5.9 0 1.385-.512 2.696-1.172 3.829-.668 1.147-1.569 2.25-2.535 3.256-1.933 2.013-4.308 3.829-6.184 5.08a2 2 0 0 1-2.218 0c-1.876-1.251-4.251-3.067-6.184-5.08-.966-1.007-1.867-2.109-2.535-3.256C1.512 12.592 1 11.28 1 9.896c0-2.99 2.192-5.9 5.6-5.9 1.607 0 2.953.42 4.016.973.51.265.952.559 1.33.85Z" fill="#686A7A" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></button><button style="cursor:pointer" class="ComparisonButton__AddToComparison-sc-qggtzt-0 lzbqf"><svg class="SVGIcon__StyledSVGIcon-sc-1fzgsce-0 icCsZM" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none"><path d="m1.525 2.5556h9.15v0.79325c0 0.42104 0.3413 0.76239 0.7623 0.7625 0.4212 1e-4 0.7627-0.34131 0.7627-0.7625v-1.3488c0-0.55229-0.4477-1-1-1h-10.2c-0.55228 0-1 0.44772-1 1v12c0 0.5523 0.44772 1 1 1h10.2c0.5523 0 1-0.4477 1-1v-1.3486c0-0.4211-0.3414-0.7625-0.7625-0.7625s-0.7625 0.3414-0.7625 0.7625v0.793h-9.15v-10.889z" fill="currentColor"></path><path d="m3.0977 4.8098c0-0.42079 0.34111-0.76191 0.7619-0.76191h4.673c0.42079 0 0.7619 0.34112 0.7619 0.76191s-0.34111 0.7619-0.7619 0.7619h-4.673c-0.42079 0-0.7619-0.34111-0.7619-0.7619z" fill="currentColor"></path><path d="m3.0977 7.8576c0-0.42079 0.34111-0.76191 0.7619-0.76191h1.5746c0.42079 0 0.76191 0.34112 0.76191 0.76191s-0.34112 0.7619-0.76191 0.7619h-1.5746c-0.42079 0-0.7619-0.34111-0.7619-0.7619z" fill="currentColor"></path><path d="m3.8596 10.143c-0.42079 0-0.7619 0.3411-0.7619 0.7619s0.34111 0.7619 0.7619 0.7619h3.8984c0.42079 0 0.76191-0.3411 0.76191-0.7619s-0.34112-0.7619-0.76191-0.7619h-3.8984z" fill="currentColor"></path><path d="m13.714 5.5714c0-0.42079-0.3412-0.7619-0.7619-0.7619-0.4208 0-0.7619 0.34111-0.7619 0.7619v1.5238h-1.5239c-0.4207 0-0.76186 0.34112-0.76186 0.76191s0.34116 0.7619 0.76186 0.7619h1.5239v1.5238c0 0.4208 0.3411 0.7619 0.7619 0.7619 0.4207 0 0.7619-0.3411 0.7619-0.7619v-1.5238h1.5238c0.4208 0 0.7619-0.34111 0.7619-0.7619s-0.3411-0.76191-0.7619-0.76191h-1.5238v-1.5238z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg></button></div></div><div class="NewBuildingItem__Row-sc-o36w9y-14 iSPtSM"><div class="NewBuildingItem__InfoBlock-sc-o36w9y-15 NewBuildingItem__LableValue-sc-o36w9y-16 iPvXby bHceKv"><div><p class="NewBuildingItem__Text-sc-o36w9y-7 NewBuildingItem__InfoLabel-sc-o36w9y-10 iUiqkY esfvPl">Ввод в эксплуатацию</p><p class="NewBuildingItem__InfoValue-sc-o36w9y-11 jZCQkA">IV кв. 2026</p></div><div><p class="NewBuildingItem__Text-sc-o36w9y-7 NewBuildingItem__InfoLabel-sc-o36w9y-10 iUiqkY esfvPl">Застройщик</p><p class="NewBuildingItem__InfoValue-sc-o36w9y-11 jZCQkA">ООО СЗ ИМПЕРИАЛ</p></div></div><div class="NewBuildingItem__TransportBlock-sc-o36w9y-18 iugPIG"></div></div></div></div></div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, "lxml")

link = soup.select_one("a[class^='NewBuildingItem__ImageWrapper']")["href"]
title = soup.select_one("a[class^='NewBuildingItem__MainTitle']")
address = soup.select_one("p[class^='NewBuildingItem__Text']")
building_id = soup.select_one("p[class*='NewBuildingItem__ObjectID']")
commissioning = soup.select_one("p[class^='NewBuildingItem__InfoValue']")
developer = soup.select("p[class^='NewBuildingItem__InfoValue']")[1]

print(link)
print(title.text)
print(address.text)
print(building_id.text)
print(commissioning.text)
print(developer.text)

Output:
https://xn--80az8a.xn--d1aqf.xn--p1ai/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82/60491
Многофункциональный комплекс "Парк"
Краснодарский край, город Г Сочи, Проспект Курортный
ID: 60491
IV кв. 2026
ООО СЗ ИМПЕРИАЛ

I assume that this is what you are trying to extract? Don't know any Russian.
